# Android Studio - Get the Image/Video file name from Uri

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera-intent

I get the wrong file name when i select a file from Gallery. I don't know what is wrong in my code. any help is much appreciated thanks

This is my selectFile method in my class AreaFragment extend Fragment

```
public void selectFile(){
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Camera","Select image","Select video","Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Add file");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_photo_black_24dp);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Camera")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Select image")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select image"), PICK_IMAGE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Select video")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("video/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select video"), PICK_VIDEO);
                }else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

This is my onActivityResult

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        final ImageView add_task_images = (ImageView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.img_task_preview);
        final LinearLayout image_wrapper = (LinearLayout) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.image_task_wrapper);
        final VideoView video_task_preview = (VideoView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.video_task_preview);
        final LinearLayout video_task_wrapper = (LinearLayout) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.video_task_wrapper);
        final TextView video_file_name = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.video_file_name);
        final TextView image_file_name = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.image_file_name);

        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                selectedImagePath = destination.getPath();

                String img_name = destination.getName();
                image_file_name.setText("File name: " + img_name ); // Get the wrong file name

                image_wrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                add_task_images.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

            } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
                int scale = 1;
                while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                        && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale *= 2;
                options.inSampleSize = scale;
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
                add_task_images.setImageBitmap(bm);

                String path = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                File image_name = new File(path);
                image_file_name.setText("File name: " + image_name.getName()); // Get the wrong file name

                image_wrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else if(requestCode == PICK_VIDEO){

                Uri videoUri = data.getData();
                video_task_preview.setVideoURI(videoUri);

                String path = videoUri.getPath();
                File filepath = new File(path);
                video_file_name.setText("File name: " + filepath.getName()); //Get the wrong file name

                video_task_wrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

at first you need to get the valid path of the media and then use file.getName() to get the file name, try this it will work.

```
             String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
             String result = null;

             CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                     getActivity(), 
               uri, proj, null, null, null);        
             Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

             if(cursor != null){
              int column_index = 
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
              cursor.moveToFirst();
              result = cursor.getString(column_index);
              Log.d("file path", result);
```